# Google Tag Assistant Difficult to fire checkout-tag + What do the words under Summary represent?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I wanted to fire my Facebook Pixel for Initiate Checkouts, however I noticed that I have 2 checkouts that are being loaded with exactly the same variables and data layer. This causes the Pixel to fire twice which I do not want. I don't really know how you can call the words below summary and what it exactly refers to (I think it is parts of the website that is being loaded) but here is a picture:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. What exactly are checkoutOption, Window Loaded, DOM Ready, checkout, etc.?
2. Is there a possibility to change or remove them completely? (In my case I would like to remove the double checkout)
3. What is the best way for me to fire the pixel only once?